# Cannot connect to the real [website.com]

Tags: google-account, chrome-for-android, samsung-galaxy-tab

I just bought a Galaxy Tab 4 and I'm trying to set it up for development.

Being behind a proxy that needs authentification, I installed drony to provide my credentials. I'm now able to surf most http websites and few secure https websites.

On the other hand, I can't get most https sites and all the google services (Play, Maps, Youtube) to work.

I tried to use the google.com website to connect to my google account, and I got a page with the following error message :  "Something is currently interfering with your secure connection to [site].
Try to reload this page in a few minutes or after switching to a new network. If you have recently connected to a new Wi-Fi network, finish logging in before reloading.

If you were to visit [site] right now, you might share private information with an attacker. To protect your privacy, Chrome will not load the page until it can establish a secure connection to the real [site]. "

Can somebody help?

Comment: Sounds like something you might have to discuss with your network administrator. We can't help without a lot more details about this proxy server and why it's blocking most HTTPS sites.

Comment: I already checked with my network administrator, the problem is not with our proxy server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it to work!

google.com (and other websites) refuse requests from hosts that doesn't have the date properly set on their device. 
At the first startup, I didn't bother setting the date on my tablet (on iOS it sets automatically).

After manually  setting the tablet's date and time, the error page is gone and I have access to all the google apps.

EDIT.
According to Izzy, it was Chrome itself that refused the connection, possibly because the certificate dates were not matching.

Comment: It's not "Google.com and other websites" refusing requests from, but your device refusing to connect *TO*: it cannot find a valid SSL certificate, as their validity dates are not matching your device date/time. So it assumes security is not granted, and refuses to connect to those "insecure sites".

Comment: I appreciate your explanation, let me mention that obvious for an Android professionnal is not obvious for any Android enthusiast. The error page was not helping and there were a lot of possible causes. I edited my answer to reflect Izzy's explaination

Comment: Sorry, no offense meant! I should take more care for my phrasing... For references, you might check [these posts](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=date+certificate), by the way.